# Is it possible to build this query in SQL or With PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have This is Tables in Oracle Database:

1- Users Table

```
╔════════╦═════════╗
║ UserID ║ Name    ║
╠════════╬═════════╣
║ 12345  ║ Scott   ║
╠════════╬═════════╣
║ 54321  ║ Jeffry  ║
╠════════╬═════════╣
║ 98765  ║ Larry   ║
╚════════╩═════════╝
```

2- ScoreTypes Table

```
╔══════════════════╦════════════╗
║ ScoreTypeID (PK) ║ Title      ║
╠══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1                ║ Football   ║
╠══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 2                ║ Volleyball ║
╠══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ 3                ║ Basketball ║
╚══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

3- UserResults

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════╗
║ UserID (FK) ║ ScoreTypeID (FK) ║ ScoreNum ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 12345       ║ 1                ║ 89       ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 12345       ║ 2                ║ 45       ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 54321       ║ 1                ║ 95       ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 54321       ║ 2                ║ 60       ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 98765       ║ 1                ║ 100      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 98765       ║ 3                ║ 35       ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════╝
```

4- ScorePolicyPasses Table

```
╔═════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID (PK) ║ ScoreTypeID (FK) ║ PassScore ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1       ║ 1                ║ 90        ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2       ║ 2                ║ 50        ║
╚═════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

What idea?

There may be records for User in Table "UserResults"
It contains a column to display score Number obtained in the specific game in table "ScoreTypes".
Each game has score pass specific to Win in Table "ScorePolicyPasses"

**I want to write a single query**
To return  the users who have the records in "UserResults Table"

but, Only those who did not go beyond the policies in "ScorePolicyPasses Table"

**Result SQL Query:**

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║ Users.UserID ║ Users.Name ║ Comment                      ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ 12345        ║ Scott      ║ Football: 89, Volleyball: 45 ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

Only one user did not achieve the results that have been previously put her policies

Soctt has score in Football 90 Good but in Volleyball 45 < 50
too, If it were football < 90 and Volleyball < 50  did not achieve

Jeffry Achieved the desired football > 90 and Volleyball > 50
Larry Achieved the desired football > 90
Although Larry has record of basketball in Table "UserResults"
But basketball has no policy in "ScorePolicyPasses Table",
Therefore, the recored will be ignored.

**Is it possible to write a query by SQL Only Or with PLSQL? And how?**

Comment: Do you need the COMMENT in the output? If so, it may be better to show rows where the score achieved is less than the pass score (ordered by user) so for each user you have a fully itemized list of "failures." More likely, however, that you don't need the COMMENT column. Please clarify. Then: if a user did not participate in a sport at all, then that should be treated the same as if the user achieved the policy minimum (it will not be used to "disqualify" or "fail" that user). Finally: please confirm that a score of 89 in football is "pass", not "fail".

Comment: Thanks, I modify post. 
Comment column is not important,
I want view ScoreNum for Each ScoreType with outputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Users ( UserID, Name ) AS
SELECT 12345, 'Scott'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 54321, 'Jeffry' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98765, 'Larry'  FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ScoreTypes ( ScoreTypeID, Title ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Football' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Volleyball' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Basketball' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE UserResults ( UserID, ScoreTypeID, ScoreNum ) AS
SELECT 12345, 1, 89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12345, 2, 45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 54321, 1, 95 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 54321, 2, 60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98765, 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 98765, 3, 35 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ScorePolicyPasses ( ID, ScoreTypeID, PassScore ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 50 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ur.UserID   AS "Users.UserID",
       MAX( Name ) AS "Users.Name",
       LISTAGG( Title || ': ' || ScoreNum, ', ' )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ur.ScoreTypeID ) AS "Comment"
FROM   UserResults ur
       INNER JOIN Users u
       ON ( ur.UserId = u.UserID )
       INNER JOIN ScoreTypes s
       ON ( ur.ScoreTypeID = s.ScoreTypeID )
       INNER JOIN ScorePolicyPasses p
       ON ( ur.ScoreTypeID = p.ScoreTypeID )
GROUP BY ur.UserID
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN ScoreNum < PassScore THEN 1 END ) > 0;
```

**Output**:

```
Users.UserID Users.Name Comment
------------ ---------- ----------------------------------------------------
       12345 Scott      Football: 89, Volleyball: 45
```

Comment: very wonderful, Strong code, Thank you MT0.... Is it possible to return in output As Columns: (select ur.ScoreNum from ur Where ur.ScoreTypeID = 1) AS "Football Score", (select ur.ScoreNum from ur Where ur.ScoreTypeID = 1) AS "Volleyball Score"

Comment: Add this into the columns selected: `MAX( CASE Name WHEN 'Football' THEN ScoreNum END ) AS "Football Score"` (and similar for Volleyball).